# AWS API Gateway multiple Integration Request per Method

Tags: aws-api-gateway

My resource /api has a method POST which proxies the body to Kinesis Firehose (and then to ES). At the same time I want it to trigger a Lambda function.

I tried adding an additional method ANY to trigger the Lambda function but API Gateway seems to preference the POST handler.

I am aware that I can trigger Lambda on POST and submit from the Lambda function to Firehose but I'd prefer having those two independent from each other.

Comment: Just wondering why you don't want to have a Lambda (not necessary the one you intend to invoke) as a middle layer. For example, integration request calls Lambda X which is a few-liner. Lambda X invokes your original Lambda and triggers kinesis? Also, do you need to collect/wait responses/statuses from both of these or you just care about firing them up?

Comment: I don't have an original Lambda, API Gateway sends directly to Kinesis.

Comment: have you considered step functions? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html

Answer (score 10):

API Gateway doesn't fork a request into multiple concurrent actions.  An `ANY` method means "any method without a defined method."  Since you also have `POST` defined, any `POST` will not see the `ANY`.

To do what you appear to be attempting -- execute a Lambda function *and* make a call to the Kinesis API, you will need to write an initial Lambda function that serves as a wrapper and performs both actions -- send a request to Kinesis and send a request to Lambda (to invoke the other Lambda function) -- asynchronously if the business logic permits it -- then marshal the results into a single coherent response that meets your needs.

This first Lambda function does not need to be in the same language as the second, so for example, if the existing Lambda function is in Java, the wrapper function could be written in Node, with no negative performance implications, since it executes independently on the other side of the Lambda API.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my observation. The main reason I wanted to avoid the extra lambda was the neat integration of Kinesis into API Gateway. Also the two actions (Kinesis and Lambda) I'm intending to do are completely independent and there is no response expect from either one. I'll accept your answer in a couple of hours.