# Api composition with AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to implement API Composition in AWS API Gateway that is described here https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html

[image: API Composition]

I have to make two calls for different modules before sending the response.

In my mind, I would be able to add more than one Integration Request and join the results with Template Mapping, but I couldn't found any documentation neither someone who have done it.

Am I getting it wrong?
Should I create my own Composition Layer in the application and API Gateway's role is just point to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I don't think API gateway support this behaviour.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865551/aws-api-gateway-multiple-integration-request-per-method)

You will need to implement your own composition layer that forks your requests and merge the reponses